# Troubles with GraphQL query running twice and not updating my data

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, graphql, apollo-client

I am using NextJS, GraphQL, Strapi, and Apollo client.

I have a bunch of data that correctly loads and displays to the page, I want to add in a simple dropdown filter that will filter this data.
I can get the filter to work for all the numbers I have added, but for the "All" value.

What I have happens, is say I select 6 from the dropdown, this loads. Then if I select "All", in the network tab I can see it runs the query with 6 as a filter again, then also runs the query correctly as I would expect, but the data never gets updated. Any reason why?

This is what my code looks like -

```
export default function Home() {
  const [runewords, setRunewords] = useState<Runewords[]>([]);
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("");
  const [sockets, setSockets] = useState<number>();
  const [searchRunewords] = useLazyQuery(SEARCH_RUNEWORDS);

  useEffect(() => {
    handleSearch();
  }, [sockets, searchText]);

  const handleSearch = async () => {
    const results = await searchRunewords({
      variables: {
        search: searchText,
        ...(sockets && {
          sockets: sockets,
        }),
      },
      fetchPolicy: "no-cache",
    });

    if (results) {
      setRunewords(results?.data?.runewords?.data);
    }
  };

  const handleSearchTextChange = async (e: any) => {
    setSearchText(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <Box>
      <Input onChange={handleSearchTextChange} />
      <Box>
        <HStack>
          <Select
            onChange={(e) => {
              setSockets(parseInt(e.target.value));
            }}
            placeholder="Sockets"
            width={"30%"}
            borderRadius={"8px"}
            backgroundColor={"white"}
          >
            <option value="">All</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
          </Select>
        </HStack>
      </Box>
      <SimpleGrid margin={"32px 32px 0px 32px"} columns={[3, 1, 2, 3]}>
        {runewords &&
          runewords.map((runeword) => (
            <Runeword key={runeword.id} {...runeword.attributes} />
          ))}
      </SimpleGrid>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: Couldn't it be because of the `StrictMode` of React? Remove it (generally it surrounds the `App`) or switch to the production mode and check again.